# XCode 6.3 Swift convertible error

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

XCode haves updated and with a new Swift update.

I have this code:

```
// load new tappable from file and place it on top of the screen beyond of sight
tappable05 = CCBReader.load("Tappable") as Tappable
tappable05.position = ccp(pipeSlim05.contentSize.width * 0.5, 
                          pipeSlim05.contentSize.height * 1.03)

tappable05.scale = 1.2

//randomize tappable color
tappable05.setRandomColor()

// setup zOrder
tappable05.zOrder = DrawingOrder.DrawingOrderTappable.rawValue

// add new tappable to scene
pipeSlim05.addChild(tappable05)
```

And I get this error:

```
CCNode! is not convertible to 'Tappable;' dod you mean to use 'as!'
```

Comment: Yes.  New to Swift 1.2 (in Xcode 6.3) downcasts now require `as!`.  Did you try changing it to `as! Tappable` ?

Comment: Dude use the converter they included. It's gonna fix all of those.

Answer (score 0):

This is the most common change in 1.2, downcasts require the !.

There is a converter that will fix that, here:

[image]

Or use the quick fix, but that is a needless hassle.